# Adjust sleep() to ensure a constant rate as accurately as possible

Tags: python, delay, sleep, rate

I have a function that takes x amount of time to run. This time follows approximately a standard distribution. Now I want this function to be executed y times per minute or per hour. How would I adjust the delays after each call to achieve that?

I am guessing that I would have to time and average the last 10(maybe?) calls, see how long they took and then make the adjustments in the delays based on that? Similar to how fps are controlled. I can't however wrap my head around exactly how to do that.

Than you.

pseudocode:

```
def repeat_x_per_hour(reps_per_hour):
start_time = time.time()
while(true):
    function(a,b,c)
    ellapsed_time = time.time()-start_time
    sleep(some_func_of_ellapsed_time(ellapsed_time, reps_per_hour))
```

Comment: Why not just sleep for `rep_number * reps_per_hour - ellapsed_time`?

Comment: Look into rate limiting tools. There are quite a few of these floating around as many API's have rate limits they enforce.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this thread and it's pretty much exactly what I needed!

https://gist.github.com/gregburek/1441055

Thanks @SuperStew for suggesting looking into rate limiting tools.